# Central Air and Hot Bedroom

Tags: central-air

We have central air in our house and with summer quickly approaching I am looking to address how hot our bedroom gets even with the AC running.

We keep our bedroom door closed and I am guessing that since there is no air return to the unit (air return for the whole house is located in the hallway off the living room) that this could be the issue.

Am I on the right track? If so, how best to try and address this other than sleeping with the bedroom door open?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely add a vent above the door's HEIGHT (explained at the end) instead or on the ceiling. If the hallway connects to other rooms, then add vents to them too. This would turn the entire hallway into a return duct of negative pressure & should've been done PROPERLY from the start.

Meaning, the vent should **NOT** be a hole straight through both sides of the wall. The vent on either side of the wall should be offset from each other by a minimum of 4-feet, for soundproofing or privacy. **YOU** (being the one stuck with the dilemma) would drill holes through wall studs or the wall's top-plate stud to "connect" the inner & outer vents.

Answer (score 0):

You are right if there's no return and the door is closed there is no flow, cut  some off the bottom of the door, or add a return vent to your bedroom so there will be enough air exchange to keep it cool

Comment: Since hot air rises and that is the air I want to move out, wouldn't be better to add a vent above the door or one in the ceiling that ties into another vent in the hallway?

Comment: Usually there is a gap at the bottom of the door and a seal / trim at the top. A vent to tie into the return would be the best way.

Comment: That would require running lots of duct work to tie directly into the return as there is no duct work for this. I thinking my best and cheapest option is to install a vent into the hallway to help move more air. I did find this question and may follow the advice. http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/how-do-i-install-a-jump-duct